# Why is Craft returning a 504 during a system update?

Tags: updating, manual-updates

There have been a few updates to the system and some of the plugins I am using. I have installed everything locally and a plugin needed to run new migrations as a result of the update.

Everything works great locally, I went to `/admin` to "Finish up" the updates.

Now I have moved the files out to my staging server. I always manually update (even though Craft will do this for me). Once all of the files have deployed, I once again visit `/admin` to run the migrations.

However, the database is quite large (> 100MB) and I am getting a `504 Gateway timeout error`.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your database is a decent size, your server is exceeding the maximum execution time. That is what is resulting in the 504.

Most likely, you will need to [disable the auto-update feature](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#backupDbOnUpdate) and manually make a backup.

[Check out this article](https://craftcms.com/support/504-gateway-timed-out-error) on how you can trouble shoot this error. (Thanks Brad)

You can also check with your hosting provider to see if they can increase the execution time.

Answer (score 2):

I've had this issue before.

It's usually to do with one of two things for me - either the [PHP script timeout](https://serverfault.com/questions/500467/apache2-proxy-timeout) value or the [FPM proxy timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829403/how-to-increase-the-execution-timeout-in-php) value.

Another method of fixing this is to change the update settings in the general Craft [configuration](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings):

```
'backupDbOnUpdate' => false,
```

Keep in mind though that you will need to back up the database yourself.